# Is HB-N106 the only hood suitable for Nikkor AF-P DX 18-55 VR lens?

Tags: lens, nikon, compatibility, lens-hood

I have **AF-P DX NIKKOR 18-55 mm f/3.5 - 5.6G VR** lens and I am looking for a hood. From lens' [official product info page](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-p_dx_18-55mmf_35-56g_vr/spec.htm), it has been noticed that the compatible hood is [HB-N106 Bayonet Hood](http://www.nikon.co.in/en_IN/product/accessories/1-nikkor-lenses/lens-hoods/lens-hood-hb-n106). Is this the only hood compatible with this lens? If not, how can I search for compatible hoods?

Comment: Google... or eBay - search 'lens hood 18-55 mm f/3.5 - 5.6G' Prices from $£€ 1

Comment: [Is there any downside to using a knock-off lens hood?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/38520/15871)

Comment: [Selecting a lens hood](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/93199/50888)

Answer (score 1):

You can find numerous options for knock-off lens hoods [on Aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=SB_20171222032830&SearchText=%20HB-N106):

[image]

Although be aware of [the pitfalls](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/38520/is-there-any-downside-to-using-a-knock-off-lens-hood) of buying a third-party lens hood.