# What should I buy? (new body vs. lens)

Tags: lens, body, sigma, nikon-d3100

Right now I have a Nikon D3100, a Sigma 50mm f1.4 (older version). Right now I have almost 1300$. What do you think I should buy? I'm hesitating between the Nikon D7100 or buying a Sigma 35mm f1.4 Art+ a flash and some other accessories. (I'm really into portrait photography)

Comment: What do you feel is limiting about your current equipment?

Comment: Szia Attila, welcome to photo.stackexchange.com. Unfortunately your question does not meet the site standards of "What to ask", especially, product recommendations are off-topic here and will quickly get voted down or closed. What is the specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: By the way, if you are into portraits, the longer focal length, the better. So the 35mm is seems to be off unless you want to photograph groups, yet still, are you sure the bokeh quality you can get from a 35mm is adequate?

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic question. The reason I asked this is because in my country Black Friday is coming next weekend and I'm really confused about buying the right equipment.

Comment: @TFuto Where should I ask questions connected to product recommendations?

Comment: @VargaAttila: Forums usually work (can get rather biased), better is to check out reviews. If you have chat rights, you can invite others to chatting here as well. This is a Q&A-type site that tries to capture answers with longer validity. You can start with another question, writing down a specific problem you want to solve with your equipment, then get advice, and then use that to select better equipment.

Comment: btw I know that for portraits the longer focal length is better, but my 50 is too tight in some situations and I thought that it'd be great to have a 50 equivalent lens on APS-C.

Comment: I have a Nikkor 35mm 1.8G, does not work out for single portraits. Google "focal length portrait examples" (without quotes) to see how the structure of the face changes with focal lengths.

Comment: @VargaAttila: E.g. see: http://petapixel.com/assets/uploads/2012/08/portraits_mini.jpg. And also see: http://petapixel.com/2012/08/12/how-focal-length-affects-your-subjects-weight-in-portraits/

Comment: or http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50035/50mm-vs-35mm-cropped/50042#50042

Answer (score 0):

I would buy the body and rent lenses as I needed them, but it is really about your preference and intended uses. The D7100 is a much better camera than the D3100. I stopped buying lenses because they are so expensive and oftentimes, you need some choices. That's where rentals can save you from breaking the bank. You can rent a $1500 lens for a weekend for less than $40 at my local photo shop. If you have a local shop, go there. Otherwise, there are plenty of sites that send rentals right to you. Hope that helps!

Comment: You can rent camera bodies, too. I use a D700 and a D5100 but always rent a D4, rather cheap these days. Moverover, bodies lose value faster than lenses.

Comment: The problem is that in my area I don't really have the opportunity to rent lenses or cameras.

Comment: @VargaAttila: where do you live? ;-)

Comment: I live in Transilvania/ Romania.